# How to write a dynamic web address code in order to web scrape?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to write a code for web scraping that will concatenate a base web address with alternating ending to retrieve specific web page data.

.

Example:

Base Address: https://www.walkscore.com/score/

Ending Address: /1234-fake-address-dr-54321-columbus-oh-12345

.

I have all of my alternate endings listed in an Excel file, in the second row and second column (data starts in cell B2), and have this code so far:

```
install.packages("openxlsx")
library(openxlsx)
install.packages("readxl")
library(readxl)
install.packages("XLConnect")
library(XLConnect)
install.packages("rio")
library(rio)
library(rvest)
install.packages('xlsx')
library(xlsx)
install.packages(“tidyverse”)
library(tidyverse)
install.packages(“readr”)
library(readr)

setwd("**personal directory**")

add <- readxl::excel_sheets("Walkability Addresses.xlsx")

**url<-html(paste("https://www.walkscore.com/score/",add$Full Address[1],sep=""))*

selector_name <- ".block-header-badge score-info-link "
walkability<-html_nodes(x = url, css = selector_name) %>%
  html_text()

script <- data.frame(add$Full Address[1]),walkability)

colnames(script) <- c("Address","Walkability Score")

for (i in 2:nrow(add)){
  
url<-html(paste("https://www.walkscore.com/score/",add$Full Address[i],sep=""))

selector_name <- ".block-header-badge score-info-link "
walkability<-html_nodes(x = url, css = selector_name) %>%
  html_text()

new_script <- data.frame(add$Full Address[i]),walkability)

colnames(new_script) <- c("Address",”Walkability Score”)  
 
script <- rbind(script, new_script)
}
```

.

For clarity,

Full Address = the column name of the ending data I want to extract, [1] = my attempt to get my code to skip one row (the header row)

*I keep getting the following error after my third step:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "url<-html(paste("https://www.walkscore.com/score/",add$Full Address"

I believe it is referring to both the $ and the [], as I tried without these symbols and was told there was no problem. how do I make a better reference to the Excel data I want to pull in so that I can make the code dynamic and able to go down the list itself? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have an issue with the `Full adress`.

The space might cause some troubles i think, and it will try to access `add$Full`

You might want to try

```
url<-html(paste("https://www.walkscore.com/score/",add$`Full Address`[i],sep=""))
```